# How to write a protective MBR in Windows?

Tags: windows, partitioning, mbr, gpt, gdisk

I have a UEFI machine with CentOS on one disk and Windows 2016 on another. The Windows installer writes the GPT protective MBR, but it doesn't follow the UEFI standard exactly, as described [here](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/GPT.htm). It writes the MBR with a single partition, as per standard, but then it makes the last sector 2^32-1 instead of the actual size of the disk.

This isn't a problem until I try to use [sgdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/sgdisk.html) to save the partition table and later restore it. The bad figure for the size confuses things and it ends up with a corrupt MBR. In CentOS, I can prevent this by using [gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/gdisk.html) to write a new protective MBR. However, it would be convenient if I could do that from Windows. Is there a way?

Comment: Is your disk larger than 2.2 TB?

Comment: No, it's smaller. I suspect that's what causes the problem, though I can't prove it.

Comment: That cannot cause the problem. What disk is it?

Comment: A Toshiba DT01ACA050, size 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GB. If I use gedit to write a new protective MBR, it uses 1953525167 for the end sector, and then the sgdisk save and restore work.

Comment: It's worse than you think : The DT01ACA050 gets its name because it has 500 GB. If it had 1 TB, it would be called DT01ACA100 ([link](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/us/product/storage-products/client-hdd/dt01acaxxx.html)). Something is very fishy with that disk - it succeeds in misleading operating systems about its capacity. Is it still under warranty?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the wrong machine! It's an HUS722T1TALA600, which I believe is 1TB.

Comment: It's now even worse - see my answer.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem I referred to in the question, detailed at the link. So the question is, is there an Windows equivalent of gdisk, that can write a correct protective MBR?

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the poster's disk is just 1 TB, my answer below does not apply.

I discovered a very surprising fact in the article
[The GPT Protective MBR and Partition Table](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/GPT.htm):

> Windows 7 always fills this field with 0xFFFFFFFF, even though the UEFI Specification states this should be "set to the size of the disk minus one" for drives under 2.2 TB.

And this is what is noted in a footnote :

> Reference and full quote: *Unified Extensible Firmware Interface Specification, Version 2.3.1, Errata C, June 27, 2012*, which states in Chapter 5, GUID Partition Table (GPT) Disk Layout, Section 5.2.3, Protective MBR, Table 15, 'SizeInLBA', on page 100: "Set to the size of the disk minus one. Set to 0xFFFFFFFF if the size of the disk is too large to be represented in this field." **Since Microsoft uses the same entry for drives smaller than 2.2 TB as it does for those over 2.2 TB, they are not following the UEFI Specification for SizeInLBA**.

So this is a case of Microsoft deciding to ignore the standard,
and there is nothing you can do about it.
A solution might possibly be to do the partition allocation under Linux.

If you are looking for a non-Microsoft utility under Windows,
see the article
[Best Free Partition Management Software](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-partition-management-software.htm), which lists free third-party
utilities which may not ignore the standard.

---

(Old answer)

I think that your disk must be larger than 2.2 TB, which is the maximum size for an MBR.

The protective MBR (or any MBR) is limited to that size.
It cannot give a larger number,
because the field in the MBR that contains the partition size has only
32 bits.

This limitation was one of the reasons that GPT became necessary when disks
larger than 2.2 TB arrived on the market.

Comment: Downvote. Why ?

Comment: Yeah it's annoying isn't it?! The first time I see one of the "real" super users complain about it. I wish there could be a mandatory (anonymous) reason for the downvote... sigh Maybe I should suggest that in meta?! PS. I wasn't the downvoter...

Comment: @Albin: Such measures were discussed on Meta but nobody ever agreed on anything.

Comment: @Albin - I suggested that a couple of years ago, but it was refused. I'm sure I'm not the only one to have done so.

Comment: @AFH Thanks I'll do some research. Would you guys be interested in opening a chat room to discuss this further or did you give up on it?

Comment: @Albin: I gave up a long time ago. Anyway, I think that SU Meta is not the right place for site changes. This is done on a higher level up in the StackOverflow hierarchy. Maybe SO Meta, but the chances are slim.

Comment: @Albin - [This](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8706/penalty-for-unexplained-down-votes) was my submission, which I subsequently accepted was a duplicate, but I received a couple of interesting comments before the duplicate was flagged, which is why I haven't quoted the duplicate.

Comment: @AFH: Interesting and convincing of the futility.